# Python-Flask-SQLAlchemy Get date column in ISO format

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, iso8601

I have a model class which looks like this

```
class Test(database.Model):
       created_date = database.Column(database.DateTime,
                                      default=datetime.utcnow,
                                      nullable=False)
```

I'm getting this via running command

```
all = Test.query.all()
```

Now, this gets me dates in format `2017-09-05 09:45:28` I want to get ISO representation of dates like `2017-09-05T09:45:28.263000`.

One option is to post-process the data I received, but what is the better approach? Is there any SQLAlchemy construct which will help me achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's clarify something, because your question might be a little bit misleading.

Test.query.all() returns list of Test objects, where each is representation of the Model that you've defined and should contain declared attributes (like creation_date).

```
>>> t = Test.query.all()
>>> t
[<Test object at 0x10010d2d0>, ...]
```

Now - creation date attribute is a datetime object and doesn't give you any specific representation per se. Instead, it contain some methods (like `__str__`, `__repr__`, `isoformat`, etc.) that helps you get desired representation of datetime object.

```
>>> t[0].created_date
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 2, 15, 34, 10, 272)
>>> t[0].created_date.isoformat()
'2017-03-02T15:34:10.000272'
```

The way how you present the data it's not something that SQLAlchemy layer should be aware of, as SQLAlchemy is ORM (model layer) and by design shouldn't lay in controller/view layer: [more on mvc](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-model-view-controller-mvc-paradigm-summarized-with-legos/)

If you really want have some predefined representation of some attribute in SQLAlchemy Models, use `@property` decorator in your `Test` class.

```
@property
def created_date(self):
    return self.created_date.isoformat()
```

More on that in SQLAlchemy documentation: [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)

Comment: Your points are correct! I was indeed missing the part that the serialization is taken care of `marshmallow` library. I've raised another question for customizing serialization  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074589/python-marshmallow-customize-formatting-of-class-member