# Python Marshmallow - Customize formatting of class member

Tags: python, serialization, marshmallow

I have Marshmallow serializer written as

```
class TestSchema(Schema):
    created_date = fields.Str(required=False)


class Test(database.Model):
       created_date = database.Column(database.DateTime,
                                      default=datetime.utcnow,
                                      nullable=False)


testSchema = TestSchema()
testSchema.dump(new Test())
```

Is there any way I can change the output of `created_date` using `created_date.isoformat()`?

Comment: Did you try fields.Date() instead of fields.Str?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fields.DateTime` marshmallow field for SQLAlchemy datetime object instead of `fields.Str`. In fact, iso format is default format, but you can specify other in `format` parameter. Docs: [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.DateTime)

Comment: This works! Thanks for the answer. Do we have to handle the exception just in case if the date is not properly stored in the database?

Comment: Hard to say. Personally, I probably wouldn't bother in case if I'd own both database and code (or try to catch exception somewhere else), but actually Marshmallow gives some list of library-oriented exceptions that you might find useful: http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#module-marshmallow.exceptions